# prolog : using elements of a list in a fact

Tags: list, prolog

I want to make a Prolog console application that shows venue name and rent for any event for a given(user input) location. So far I have been able to create a list of venues of a given(user input) location.

My code is given below.

```
listing(venue_location).
listing(venue_seating).
listing(venue_overhead).

venue_location(washington_party_hall1, washington).
venue_location(washington_party_hall2, washington).
venue_location(newyork_party_hall1, newyork).
venue_location(newyork_party_hall2, newyork).

venue_capacity(washington_party_hall1,300).
venue_capacity(washington_party_hall2,450).
venue_capacity(newyork_party_hall1, 340).
venue_capacity(newyork_party_hall2,500).

venue_rent(washington_party_hall1,1350).
venue_rent(washington_party_hall2,1200).
venue_rent(newyork_party_hall1,1500).
venue_rent(newyork_party_hall2,1000).

main:-
   write("Enter a location"),nl,write("->"),
   read(Loc),
   findall(X,venue_location(X,Loc),Venues),
   write(Venues).
```

This gives the following output:

```
Enter a location
->washington.
[washington_party_hall1,washington_party_hall2]
true.
```

Is there a way to use the `venues` list in `venue_rent` fact to get every list element's rent?
I want to display the name of these venues with their rents in this way:

```
washington_party_hall1   1350
washington_party_hall2   1200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that if you have a given venue, say `Venue`, you can get the rent from your facts:

```
?- Venue = washington_party_hall1, venue_rent(Venue, Rent).
Rent = 1350
```

If you want to get the rent for all of the venues in a list `Venues`, you can use `member/2`:

```
?- Venues = [washington_party_hall1,washington_party_hall2], member(Venue, Venues), venue_rent(Venue, Rent).
```

That's the basic query structure of what you want. Now if you want to write things to the terminal in a nice format, you can use a failure driven loop, which is a common way to display a list of items in a formatted fashion:

```
write_venue_rents(Venues) :-
    member(Venue, Venues),
    venue_rent(Venue, Rent),
    write(Venue), write(' '), write(Rent), nl,
    fail.
```

This doesn't give you aligned columns, but you get the idea. You can look up the formatting options and predicates for Prolog to format the output to your taste.

Another way is to use `maplist/2`:

```
% Write out the rent for a given venue
write_venue_rent(Venue) :-
    venue_rent(Venue, Rent),
    write(Venue), write(' '), write(Rent), nl.

% Write out the rent for a list of venues
write_venue_rents(Venues) :-
    maplist(write_venue_rent, Venues).
```

I think the `maplist/2` version is more elegant.

Comment: I was looking something just like `maplist/2`. Can you provide some good documentation showing example of this predicate? I may have to use this predicate frequently.

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib I haven't found any good online documentation with examples, unfortunately. But it's pretty straightforward. `maplist` iterates a goal over one or more lists, with the general expectation that the lists are all the same length. There is some limit to the number of arguments. You would use the fact that, for example, `call(goal(a), b)` is equivalent to `call(goal(a, b))`. So, `maplist(foo(X, Y), L1, L2)` simply calls `foo(X, Y, E1, E2)` for each element `E1` of `L1` and `E2` of `L2`.

Comment: If the given goal of `maplist/2` fails for some list elements, will it stop the process? Can I use some failsafe options in the `maplist/2` goal?

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib `maplist/n` fails on the first iterated call that fails.

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib if you wanted `maplist/n` to keep going, you could define a predicate such as `map_goal(...) :- goal(...) -> true ; true.` then call `maplist(map_goal, List, ...)` which would continue executing `goal` for each member of `List`, etc, until the list was exhausted.

Comment: Can I pass an extra `atom` or `argument` to `maplist/2` predicate's `goal`? Or I have to use a different approach. A quick feedback would be really helpful.

Comment: Can I pass an extra `atom` or `argument` to `maplist/2` predicate's `goal`? Or I have to use a different approach. A quick feedback would be really helpful.

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib yes you can pass arguments to the goal. See the example in my prior, longer comment with `foo(X, Y)`. The goal is `foo(X, Y)` so I'm passing `X` and `Y` to each call of `foo/4`. The 3rd and 4th arguments come from the lists. If you want more details, you should ask a new Stackoverflow question and explain what you are trying to achieve.